# How to identify the MQTT topic that received the message?

Tags: java, mqtt

The client is subscribed to a x / # topic. There is the possibility of receiving message in the topics x / start and x / stop, and depending on the topic, it performs an action. I wonder how I can identify if it's coming up in the start or stop topic.

In the current code, I send an "action" key in the JSON: "start" or "stop". I want to delete this key and use the format that said above, identifying the topic.

Any further information they deem necessary, please request that I edit the post!

JDK 8

The code:

```
 private MqttCallback callback = new MqttCallback() {
        public void connectionLost(Throwable throwable) {
            try {
                connect();
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
            String messageReceived = new String(mqttMessage.getPayload());
            actionPerformed(messageReceived);
        }

        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken iMqttDeliveryToken) {
        }

    };

private void actionPerformed(String message) throws IOException {
    ClientDTO clientDTO = new ObjectMapper().readValue(message, ClientDTO.class);
    if (clientDTO.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
        startView(clientDTO);
    } else if (clientDTO.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
        stopView();
    }

}

public void connect() throws MqttException {
    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setUserName("a_nice_username");
    options.setPassword("a_cool_password".toCharArray());
    options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
    MqttClient client = new MqttClient("someaddress", MqttClient.generateClientId());
    client.setCallback(callback);
    try {
        client.connect(options);
        client.subscribe(topic);
        TaskbarIcon.alteraIconeOnline();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        TaskbarIcon.alteraIconeOffline();
    }
}

public void tipoConexao(int tipoConex) throws IOException {
    switch (tipoConex) {
        case 0:
            topic += "/operador/" + getIdReceived() + "/#";
            System.out.println(topic);
            break;

        //etc

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `s` in this method is the topic: `public void messageArrived(String s, MqttMessage mqttMessage)`

As is very well documented [here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/files/javadoc/org/eclipse/paho/client/mqttv3/MqttCallback.html#messageArrived-java.lang.String-org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage-):

> **messageArrived**
>
> *void messageArrived(java.lang.String topic, MqttMessage message) throws java.lang.Exception*
>
> This method is called when a message arrives from the server.
>
> This method is invoked synchronously by the MQTT client. An acknowledgment is not sent back to the server until this method
>   returns cleanly.
>
> If an implementation of this method throws an Exception, then the client will be shut down. When the client is next re-connected, any
>   QoS 1 or 2 messages will be redelivered by the server.
>
> Any additional messages which arrive while an implementation of this method is running, will build up in memory, and will then back up
>   on the network.
>
> If an application needs to persist data, then it should ensure the data is persisted prior to returning from this method, as after
>   returning from this method, the message is considered to have been
>   delivered, and will not be reproducible.
>
> It is possible to send a new message within an implementation of this callback (for example, a response to this message), but the
>   implementation must not disconnect the client, as it will be
>   impossible to send an acknowledgment for the message being processed,
>   and a deadlock will occur.
>
> Parameters:
>
> *topic* - name of the topic on the message was published to
>
> *message* - the actual message.
>
> Throws:
>
> *java.lang.Exception* - if a terminal error has occurred, and the client should be shut down.

Comment: Wow, I did not understand very well, but now it's clear! Thank you!